# Balanced Partition in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, partitioning

In haskell, how can I generate a balanced partition of a set?

Assuming I have a set `{1,3,4,6,9}`, a balanced partition of that set would be `s1{9,3}` and `s2{6,4,1}`, seeing as `s1-s2` is `1`.

Answer (score 6):

Well, for brute force, we can generate all partitions recursively by generating partitions for the tail and then putting the head on the left list or the right:

```
partitions :: [a] -> [([a], [a])]
partitions [] = [([], [])]
partitions (x : xs) = let ps = partitions xs in
    [(x : ys, zs) | (ys, zs) <- ps] ++ [(ys, x : zs) | (ys, zs) <- ps]
```

have a way to compute the unbalance:

```
unbalance :: Num a => ([a], [a]) -> a
unbalance (ys, zs) = abs (sum ys - sum zs)
```

and then put it all together:

```
balancedPartition :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> ([a], [a])
balancedPartition = minimumBy (comparing unbalance) . partitions
```

Here's the complete module:

```
module Balance where

import Data.List(minimumBy)
import Data.Ord(comparing)

partitions :: [a] -> [([a], [a])]
partitions [] = [([], [])]
partitions (x : xs) = let ps = partitions xs in
    [(x : ys, zs) | (ys, zs) <- ps] ++ [(ys, x : zs) | (ys, zs) <- ps]

unbalance :: Num a => ([a], [a]) -> a
unbalance (ys, zs) = abs (sum ys - sum zs)

balancedPartition :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> ([a], [a])
balancedPartition = minimumBy (comparing unbalance) . partitions
```

Comment: @DeepRR, According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), this problem is NP-hard. So there is very little hope of finding anything better than a brute-force solution, although there may be better brute-force solutions. The first optimization I would consider is combining the unbalance calculation with the partitioning. You may also want to try to sort the list and modify the order in which you construct partitions to make it more likely that you'll find a perfect partition early, if there is one.

Comment: @dfeuer there are a bunch of solutions that do better than a brute force method.

Comment: @genisage, if the problem is truly NP-hard, then these solutions can only do better than brute force in some cases (maybe even many cases). Unless of course I somehow missed the news of someone proving P=NP....

Comment: @dfeuer quicksort only does better than bubble sort in some cases. But since quicksort is a big improvement in the average case, I don't feel bad about saying it's better.
When you say there's little hope of finding anything better, there's a chance the OP (or future readers) will listen to you and not look for other solutions. Then they won't learn about dynamic programming or greedy algorithms or differencing algorithms and that would be sad.
While it's true that any solution will probably have an exponential worst case, there may be better techniques than brute force for a given setting.

Comment: Also, in the (probably fairly common) case where you have an upper bound for the set - like you would if it was a set of `Int`s - the dynamic programming approach is quadratic. Although it will usually have a large constant factor.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that does a little better:

```
balancedPartition :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> ([a], [a])
balancedPartition = snd . head . partitionsByBadness . sort
  where
    -- recursively builds a list of possible partitionings and their badness
    -- sorted by their (increasing) badness
    partitionsByBadness []     = [(0, ([], []))]
    partitionsByBadness (x:xs) = let res = partitionsByBadness xs
                                     withX = map (      (+x) *** first  (x:)) res
                                     sansX = map (subtract x *** second (x:)) res
                                 in merge withX $ normalize sansX

    -- When items are added to the second list, the difference between the sums
    -- decreases - and might become negative
    -- We take those cases and swap the lists, so that the first list has always
    -- a greater sum and the difference is always positive
    -- So that we can sort the list again (with linear complexity)
    normalize xs = let (neg, pos) = span ((<0) . fst) xs
                   in merge pos $ reverse $ map (negate *** swap) neg

-- merge two sorted lists (as known from mergesort, but
-- omits "duplicates" with same badness)
merge :: Ord k => [(k, v)] -> [(k, v)] -> [(k, v)]
merge []         zss        = zss
merge yss        []         = yss
merge yss@(y:ys) zss@(z:zs) = case comparing fst y z of
                                LT -> y : merge ys zss
                                EQ -> merge ys zss
                                GT -> z : merge yss zs
```

Comment: Other interesting and optimized solutions can be found at [this university contest](https://www21.in.tum.de/teaching/info2/WS1415/wettbewerb.html#woche5)

Answer (score 1):

Bin packing works pretty well:

```
% stack ghci --package Binpack
λ: import Data.BinPack
λ: let bins numberOfBins items = let totalSize = sum items; binSize = succ (totalSize `div` (max 1 numberOfBins)) in binpack WorstFit Decreasing id (replicate numberOfBins (emptyBin binSize)) items
λ: bins 2 [1,3,4,6,9]
([(0,[3,9]),(1,[1,4,6])],[])
```

If you know your input will fit into the bins you can extract out the partitions:

```
λ: map snd . fst . bins 2 $ [1,3,4,6,9]
[[3,9],[1,4,6]]
```